# for [ f(n) = Sum(1:n) , g(n) = n^2 ] , why does ( f isIn O(g) AND g isIn O(f) ) hold?

Tags: asymptotics

An exercise solution claims that for
f(n) = Sum(1:n) , g(n) = n^2
it holds that f isIn O(g) and g isIn O(f).

I don't understand why this is, as it seems to me that
f isIn O(n) and g isIn O(1), because f contains n loop iterations while g contains a single multiplication regardless of the value of n. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes that sum(1:n) means $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$).

When we say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, we mean that $f(n)$ *as a function* is asympotically at most a constant multiple of $g(n)$.  Intuitively, it means that $g(n)$ *grows at least as fast as* $f(n)$.  Formally, it means something like $\limsup \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty$.

This does not say anything about the *time it takes to compute* $f$ and $g$.  If we want to say that one algorithm $A$ takes less time to compute than another algorithm $B$, we would *first* let $f(n)$ be the "runtime" for $A$ and $g(n)$ be the runtime for $B$, and then we would say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$.  We would NOT say that $A = O(B)$.

**TL;DR**: a function is not the same as an algorithm.  Big-oh notation is used to compare functions, which represent run-times.